# How to parse time based tokens in java ?(1m 1M 1d 1Y 1W 1S)

Tags: java, datetime, duration, localdate

I gets following strings from FE:

```
1m
5M
3D
30m
2h
1Y
3W
```

It corresponds to 1 minute, 5 months,3 days, 30 minutes, 2 hours, 1 year, 3 weeks.

Is there mean in java to parse it?

I want to manipulate(add/minus) with Instant(or LocalDatetTime). Is there way to do it in java?

Comment: Write your own class with all the fields mentioned and implement methods based on your requirement.

Comment: You may want to look into [`java.time.Duration.parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`java.time.Period.parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: Are the `1m` and `30m` added together? Or was it a typo and one of the two is supposed to be `s` for seconds?

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen, it is not a typo. We can get request to add 1 minute and some time later to reduce 30 minutes

Comment: @ernest_k, good point but I have to add 'P' at the begining

Comment: Well, you cannot add or subtract weeks, months or years to or from an `Instant`.

Comment: @Ole V.V.,   it works: `Period period = Period.parse("P1W");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime result = localDateTime.minus(period);`

Comment: @gstackoverflow I just discovered that a period of weeks work with `Instant` too. Months and years don’t. All do with `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @Ole V.V. I am not sure I got what you mean

Comment: @gstackoverflow `Instant.now().plus(Period.parse("P5M"))` throws an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`.

Comment: @Ole V.V. thx it is clear now. Good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Period` & `Duration`

I consider the following solution simple and pretty general (not fully general).

```
public static TemporalAmount parse(String feString) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(feString.charAt(feString.length() - 1))) {
        return Period.parse("P" + feString);
    } else {
        return Duration.parse("PT" + feString);
    }
}
```

It seems that your date-based units (year, month, week, day) are denoted with uppercase abbreviations (`Y`, `M`, `W` and `D`) while the time-based ones (hour and minute) are lowercase (`h` and `m`). So I test the case of the last character of the string to decide whether to parse into a `Period` or a `Duration`. I exploit the fact that both of `Period.parse` and `Duration.parse` accept the letters in either case.

You wanted to add or subtract the durations to and from `Instant` or `LocalDateTime`. This works in *most* cases. Let’s see:

```
    String[] timeAmountStrings = { "1m", "5M", "3D", "30m", "2h", "1Y", "3W" };
    LocalDateTime base = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 1, 0, 0);
    for (String tas : timeAmountStrings) {
        TemporalAmount amount = parse(tas);
        System.out.println("String: " + tas + " parsed: " + amount + " added: " + base.plus(amount));

        try {
            System.out.println("Added to Instant: " + Instant.EPOCH.plus(amount));
        } catch (DateTimeException dte) {
            System.out.println("Adding to Instant didn’t work: " + tas + ' ' + dte);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> String: 1m parsed: PT1M added: 2019-03-01T00:01
> Added to Instant: 1970-01-01T00:01:00Z
>
> String: 5M parsed: P5M added: 2019-08-01T00:00
> Adding to Instant didn’t work: 5M java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Months
>
> String: 3D parsed: P3D added: 2019-03-04T00:00
> Added to Instant: 1970-01-04T00:00:00Z
>
> String: 30m parsed: PT30M added: 2019-03-01T00:30
> Added to Instant: 1970-01-01T00:30:00Z
>
> String: 2h parsed: PT2H added: 2019-03-01T02:00
> Added to Instant: 1970-01-01T02:00:00Z
>
> String: 1Y parsed: P1Y added: 2020-03-01T00:00
> Adding to Instant didn’t work: 1Y java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Years
>
> String: 3W parsed: P21D added: 2019-03-22T00:00
> Added to Instant: 1970-01-22T00:00:00Z
> ```

We see that adding to `LocalDateTime` works in all cases. Adding to `Instant` works in most cases, only we cannot add a period of months or years to it.

Comment: So we can use LocalDateTime as a private object and convert to to instant in the last line of method

Comment: Yes, @gstackoverflow, if you know what time zone to use for the conversion. And if you do, it may be safer to use a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @ Ole V.V. I am curious to know why  ZonedDateTime is safer than LocalDateTime? Because of providing timezone during conversion?

Comment: Good question, @gstackoverflow, thanks. Because of summer time (DST) and other anomalies, the clock may be turned forward or backward on a particular date. When adding or subtracting hours or minutes across that point in time, `ZonedDateTime` will give you the correct number of hours or minutes. `LocalDateTime` won’t know about the anomaly and will just add or subtract as though no adjustment of time had taken place and thus not give the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869074/642706) is correct, clever, and well-done. I would take it one step further.

## `PeriodDuration`

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project adds functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. Among its offerings is the [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class, combining a `Period` (years-month-days) with a `Duration` (hours-minutes-seconds-nanos).

By the way, let me caution you about combining the two concepts. While that may seem fine intuitively, if you ponder a bit you may see it as problematic depending on your business logic.

Anyways, let’s adapt the code seen in the other Answer.

- If the input is uppercase, we create a string in standard [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format, and parse it as a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html), adding that result to our `PeriodDuration` object.
- If the input is lowercase, we create a string in standard ISO 8601 duration format, parse it as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html), and add the result to our `PeriodDuration` object.

Code:

```
List < String > inputs = List.of( "1m" , "5M" , "3D" , "30m" , "2h" , "1Y" , "3W" );
PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.ZERO;
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    String s = input.trim();
    String lastLetter = s.substring( s.length() - 1 );
    int codepoint = Character.codePointAt( lastLetter , 0 );
    if ( Character.isUpperCase( codepoint ) )
    {
        String x = "P" + s;
        Period p = Period.parse( x );
        pd = pd.plus( p );
    } else
    { // Else, lowercase.
        String x = "PT".concat( s ).toUpperCase();
        Duration d = Duration.parse(x );
        pd = pd.plus( d );
    }
}
System.out.println( "pd.toString(): " + pd );
```

> P1Y5M24DT2H31M

Comment: Very good answer. "if you ponder a bit you may see it as problematic depending on your business logic." Could you explain this point please ?

Comment: @davidxxx Well, the spinning of the earth has nothing to do with the earth’s orbit around the sun. The first we track by time-of-day (noon is when the sun is directly overhead). The second we track by calendar. Combining the two is messy and awkward. So we have Leap Year most every four years. If you apply your span-of-time over dates that do or don’t cross Leap Day, your calendar result will vary by a day. If you simultaneously care about hours-minutes-seconds, well, that seems kind of silly in the face of being off by an entire day/date. It all depends on the logic of your business problem.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since both years and  minutes are included, I recommend you to use a pair of `Duration` and `Period` parsing as mentioned in the comment. Use the static methods [`Period::parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`Duration.parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) with their default formats (`PnDTnHnMn.nS` for `Duration` and  `PnYnMnD` for `Period`) since they don't provide a way to translate custom expression like that.

For this use case, you have to create your own mapping between your expression and the given format.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct parse, but you could make your own:

```
// TODO: Proper variable/method names, comments, logging, code format, etc.
java.time.LocalDateTime changeDateTimeByString(java.time.LocalDateTime current, String part,
                                               boolean increaseOrDecrease){
  java.time.LocalDateTime newDateTime = null;

  Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(part.replaceAll("\\D",""));
  if(part.contains("S"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusSeconds(amount) : current.minusSeconds(amount);
  else if(part.contains("m"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusMinutes(amount) : current.minusMinutes(amount);
  else if(part.contains("h"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusHours(amount) : current.minusHours(amount);
  else if(part.contains("D"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusDays(amount) : current.minusDays(amount);
  else if(part.contains("W"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusDays(amount * 7) : current.minusDays(amount * 7);
  else if(part.contains("M"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusMonths(amount) : current.minusMonths(amount);
  else if(part.contains("Y"))
    newDateTime = increaseOrDecrease ? current.plusYears(amount) : current.minusYears(amount);
  else
    System.err.println("Unknown format: " + part);

  System.out.println("New dateTime after "+(increaseOrDecrease?"adding":"removing")+" "+part+": "+newDateTime);
  return newDateTime;
}
```

The parameters of the method are a String as specified by you in the question; a boolean whether you want to add or move this; and the input-date you want to modify. It will then return the modified date (Java 8+ `java.time.LocalDateTime` is used in this case). I.e.: `changeDateTimeByString(dateTime, "1m", true);` will add 1 minute; `changeDateTimeByString(dateTime, "2Y", false);` will remove 2 years.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##rVVNb9pAEL3zK0Z7sgs1TauqElEUtfWhlUpTlVQRanpY7AFM9sPaXYNQlN9Ox9gOELArmV5g1m9m3tv17POCL/nrRfyw2USCWwtDnqjHDkCaTUQSgXXc0d9SJzFIgryRM4ma/f4D3M/TABbUIHCJxOCbjrgIucNbWkFcBVd1KYHSK8@/3HYZra1DGejMBSkROKE89jkzBpV77jQA1q3ismyPJJpzNcOq96d1IdSrMnrALiTrgTNZq@L3wzOK34VUPOXCtqt@I88pfzs/Q/nF@Czld4fUp97yT7SZaHjJTx366ffh9ia8GcAPo1M0sOQm4ROBfYlurmNQXKLtQaSlpImhSOjZjMTkj2KEqTaSux6giwLqVg513eTW7Ks2vRjTHhR5kHJDi4nWArmCREUGucUbE2IR/ePeKFyFuzNWmRCXnW3BV@VwRnvnUmd0K66qBwERWqSFlzMHBlPBI/wohMfu72nwGPPL40@mRUqklaO7bD02ImwLwQveY9lwXe00SEVmR0hdYusVanwYPKMyUUdwwY80RidEyNYihkTlsFbEC7hRxLy1iC86M7USDsBGAWFrASFf1/LvY430d/@DHl7BhyYJW7xRxrD9LFCPef0oHKCNEsatJYyR10/CAbgTUDKVzojG7Jzxl3qgL6Qq3YuMEbpbc/FLQzjlpt9xtbNoPnXkF6zrHSu/ZjyOya3YgBmUepmHfpdRcs7QZbkN7@2@FGzQZUbtH0vh0E@bzV8)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is you should create your own parser method like this one using java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit and then you can use any framework to add seconds

```
private static long convertToSeconds(int value, char unit)
{
    long ret = value;
    switch (unit)
    {
    case 'd':
        ret = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(value);
        break;
    case 'h':
        ret = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(value);
        break;
    case 'm':
        ret = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(value);
        break;
    case 's':
        break;
    default:
        // fail
        break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: are you seeking advice how to solve it or complete solution? :) adding month or year makes no sense in my opinion, there is no standard size for it. Months have different length and there are also leap years

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by @Achinta Jha, you can implement yourself a simple parsing logic, with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] inputs = {"1m", "5M", "3D"/*, "30m", "2h", "1Y", "3W"*/};

        Arrays.stream(inputs)
                .map(x -> Parse(x))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private static final Map<Character, Function<String, Duration>> parsers = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        parsers.put('m', txt -> Duration.ofMinutes(Integer.parseInt(txt)));
        parsers.put('M', txt -> Duration.ofDays(30 * Integer.parseInt(txt)));
        parsers.put('D', txt -> Duration.ofDays(Integer.parseInt(txt)));
    }

    private static Duration Parse(String txt) {
        Character last = txt.charAt(txt.length() - 1);
        Function<String, Duration> parser = parsers.get(last);
        return parser.apply(txt.substring(0, txt.length() - 1));
    }
```

This is a simple, explanatory implementation, with neither error/`null`s handling nor full support for the proposed inputs.
Note that `Duration` does not support a static `ofMonths` method: I supposed you intended `30 days`, but is up to you to adjust the code to your desired semantic.

In order to add/subtract `Duration`s you can use non static methods of [`Duration` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Spring already does this but not with all the same options as you. [Their implementation is](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3cf63617f1e4afab5172881f6db3a690d4b10a1c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/config/EnvironmentMeterFilter.java)

```
private static Duration simpleParse(String rawTime) {
    if (rawTime == null || rawTime.isEmpty())
        return null;
    if (!Character.isDigit(rawTime.charAt(0)))
        return null;

    String time = rawTime.toLowerCase();
    return tryParse(time, "ns", Duration::ofNanos)
            .orElseGet(() -> tryParse(time, "ms", Duration::ofMillis).orElseGet(
                    () -> tryParse(time, "s", Duration::ofSeconds).orElseGet(
                            () -> tryParse(time, "m", Duration::ofMinutes).orElseGet(
                                    () -> tryParse(time, "h", Duration::ofHours)
                                            .orElseGet(() -> tryParse(time, "d",
                                                    Duration::ofDays)
                                                            .orElse(null))))));
}

private static Optional<Duration> tryParse(String time, String unit,
        Function<Long, Duration> toDuration) {
    if (time.endsWith(unit)) {
        String trim = time.substring(0, time.lastIndexOf(unit)).trim();
        try {
            return Optional.of(toDuration.apply(Long.parseLong(trim)));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot's users:

You can use the converter [StringToDurationConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b17eb9d6b599976a1a7d21987a0d7175ac1a1f8f/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/convert/StringToDurationConverter.java) in order to parse simple inputs like 5s, 12h, 1d and so.

In its implementation, we can find the [DurationStyle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5ec0c7ed12686d0e1794b6a9e8c40f8ff955230f/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/convert/DurationStyle.java) class.

```
Duration parsed = DurationStyle.detectAndParse("12h");
```

Also, we can see some additional examples in the [unit tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5ec0c7ed12686d0e1794b6a9e8c40f8ff955230f/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/convert/DurationStyleTests.java).

Be aware, complex inputs are not supported!